# Is there a maximum supported value for AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY?

Tags: activemq-classic

Is there a max supported value of [ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY](https://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/ScheduledMessage.html#AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY)?

We are looking at a delay between 48 hours and a week and I cannot find a documented value that is the maximum. I know that a `long` can hold a [sufficient value](https://www.advancedconverter.com/unit-conversions/time-conversion/weeks-to-milliseconds), but I don't know if there are internal limitations.

---

PS- In case people are to ask, we delete account data 48 hours after the account is canceled, so we are looking to have the delete account data job read the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell by looking at the source code I don't see any arbitrary limit. The message should obviously be persistent and the persistent scheduler should be properly configured so that if the broker has to restart during the delay everything will still work.